# How to avoid index_merge in a query?

Tags: index, optimization, mysql-5.5

I have multiple queries using index_merge but for put an example, I show you the following query

```
EXPLAIN select count(*) From Clientes  Where id_campana='1849' and id_empresa='55' and (id_estado_cliente='1' or id_estado_cliente='5' or id_estado_cliente='9'  or id_estado_cliente='10' or id_estado_cliente='13' or id_estado_cliente='7');

Running Explain Statement, this was the result

+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type        | possible_keys                                                                       | key                   | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Clientes | index_merge | id_empresa,id_campana,id_estado_cliente,id_empresa_campana,idx_mejora_perf_clientes | id_empresa,id_campana | 2,4     | NULL | 35564 | Using intersect(id_empresa,id_campana); Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

The only thing I have done to optimize query is create a compound query and use index_hint

this are the indexes which exist on this table

```
+----------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Clientes |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id                  | A         |    59405824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          0 | id_id_empresa            |            1 | id                  | A         |    59405824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          0 | id_id_empresa            |            2 | id_empresa          | A         |    59405824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id                       |            1 | id                  | A         |    59405824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id_empresa               |            1 | id_empresa          | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id_campana               |            1 | id_campana          | A         |       61752 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id_estado_cliente        |            1 | id_estado_cliente   | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id_empresa_campana       |            1 | id_empresa          | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | id_empresa_campana       |            2 | id_campana          | A         |       27982 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | idx_mejora_perf_clientes |            1 | id_empresa          | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | idx_mejora_perf_clientes |            2 | id_campana          | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | idx_mejora_perf_clientes |            3 | id_estado_cliente   | A         |       18363 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Clientes |          1 | idx_mejora_perf_clientes |            4 | id_resultado_agente | A         |      110214 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

but the problem if the developers will modify this statement to solve this condition but my doubt is exist something method to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Start by cleaning up the existing indexes:

`id` isn't useful as `id` the primary key already and should be dropped.

Both `id_empresa` and `id_empresa_campana` are superseded by `idx_mejora_perf_clientes` because `idx_mejora_perf_clientes` begins with the entire index columns of `id_empresa` and `id_empresa_campana` and these two indexes can be dropped.

With those removed hopefully your query will result in a range search on `idx_mejora_perf_clientes`. It could bad statistics or and old mysql version that doesn't see this as the preferred option.

Failing that you can remove `index_merge_intersection` from the `optimizer_switch` session variable for this query.

ref: [mysql manual on index merge](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-intersection)

Comment: I cannot drop indexes id_empresa and id_empresa_campana because of unknowledge of the code from the application, the only thing that I did was to create idx_mejora_perf_clientes, those indexes were created by the previous developers of the application and the previous year I was hired by the company as dba to improve this application but with minimal impact